# Return a value by using MATCH, INDEX or VLOOKUP with paired search terms

Tags: vba, excel, match, vlookup

I'm trying to return a value based on whether other certain values are in a row. I have two sheets in Excel that I'm working on and can't get correct formula to return a value using VLOOKUP, INDEX or MATCH. The following is an example of the spreadsheets I have:

```
Sheet 1
Segment         Node           Value

ACDC            Acadian          300
Ventura         Acadian           50
LooseGoose      Acadian          600
Dave            Haynes           500

Sheet 2
Segment         Node           Value
ACDC            Acadian
```

So I'm trying to write a function that'll return the value in Sheet 2 if the segment and node names match each other compared to how they are in Sheet 1.

Comment: Its suppose to look like this, it didn't come out right.

Comment: I'm working in Excel. I have any empty column that I'm trying to write a formula for, where I return the value in Sheet 1 based on whether the segment and node names match in Sheet 2 compared to whats in Sheet 1 already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Segment` is in A1 of both sheets, insert a new ColumnA in `Sheet 1` with:

```
=B2&"|"&C2
```

in A2 copied down to suit, then in C2 of `Sheet 2`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&"|"&B2,'Sheet 1'!A:D,4,0)
```

copied down to suit.